# How to SELECT DISTINCT from a pandas hdf5store?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have a large amount of data in an HDFStore (as a table), on the order of 80M rows with 1500 columns.  Column A has integer values ranging between 1 and 40M or so.  The values in column A are not unique and there may be between 1 and 30 rows with the same column A value.  In addition, all rows which share a common value in column A will also have a common value in column B (not the same value as column A though).

I would like to do a select against the table to get a list of column A values and their corresponding column B values.  The equivalent SQL statement would be something like `SELECT DISTINCT ColA, ColB FROM someTable`  What are some ways to achieve this?  Can it be done such that the results of the query are stored directly into another table in the HDF5Store?

Comment: To clarify, I'm looking for solutions which will work out of core.  With data on the scale that I'm processing, trying to keep everything in memory isn't feasible.

Comment: one approach that I've tried is to do a select against the store, pulling all rows with ColA  > someValue & ColB < someOtherValue, however, that method is unsatisfactory since for any particular range of values, I could have anywhere from no row, to several million rows, so keeping the size of the task relatively consistent is very difficult.

Answer (score 2):

#### Blocked Algorithms

One solution would be to look at [`dask.dataframe`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) which implements a subset of the Pandas API with blocked algorithms.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_hdf('myfile.hdf5', '/my/data', columns=['A', 'B'])
result = df.drop_duplicates().compute()
```

In this particular case `dd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`  would pull out a medium-sized block of rows, perform the `pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates` call and store the (hopefully smaller) result.  It would do this for all blocks, concatenate them, and then perform a final `pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates` on the concatenated intermediate result.  You could also do this with just a for loop.  Your case is a bit odd in that you also have a large number of unique elements.  This might still be a challenge to compute even with blocked algorithms.  Worth a shot though.

#### Column Store

Alternatively you should consider looking into a storage format that can store your data as individual columns.  This would let you collect just the two columns that you need, `A` and `B`, rather than having to wade through all of your data on disk.  Arguably you should be able to fit 80 million rows into a single Pandas dataframe in memory.  You could consider [`bcolz`](http://bcolz.blosc.org/) for this.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, you tried something like this and it didn't work?

```
import pandas
import tables
import pandasql
```

check that your store is the type you think it is:

in: `store`

out: `<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>`

You can select a table from a store like this:

```
df = store.select('tablename')
```

Check that it worked:

in: `type(tablename)`

out: `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

Then you can do something like this:

`q = """SELECT DISTINCT region, segment FROM tablename"""`

`distinct_df = (pandasql.sqldf(q, locals()))`

(note that you will get deprecation warnings doing it this way, but it works)

Comment: There are various ways to do it in memory, such as the pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates() method.  That's what I'm currently using for small portions of my data.  The problem is that it won't scale when the data is too big to be processed in memory.

Comment: have you looked at pySpark? there's also this: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/07/ibis-on-impala-python-at-scale-for-data-science/